# Can the permanent residents of Black Mirror's San Junipero 'travel' as freely as visitors?

Tags: black-mirror

In a major plot development during the San Junipero episode of Black Mirror's third season, we discover that the visitors can 'travel' to different time periods each time they visit, because we see the protagonists Yorkie and Kelly first in 1987 then other eras. This is because they are actually 'visiting' San Junipero in a virtual reality setting each week. Hence can choose to visit different eras depending on their mood each time they visit. E.g. we saw the 80s, 90s, 2000s.

However, can permanent residents do the same thing?

Because they have actually passed over (i.e. died and uploaded their consciousness to the virtual reality simulation), can they still choose to 'visit' different eras for San Junipero? Or are they 'stuck' with whatever era they selected at the moment they crossed over?

We know that both visitors and permanent residents can change clothing appearance. Hence, it would seem logical that they could also do the other. But, there is nothing else I can find to indicate one way or the other if it would be possible.

If they ARE able to do this, then I would be curious how often they can and how they do it. E.g.

- Are they only able to 'switch' once/week like visitors?  Or, can they do it more frequently.
- Can they simply 'think' themselves into the other era similar to how they can change clothes?

Any in-universe or out-universe source giving a clue on this (e.g. director interview) would be welcome.

Comment: I would imagine so. Why offer a feature to your trial users that you would take away from your paid users?

Comment: I agree and would think so as well. But, I can't find anything to confirm it.  Too, if it IS possible, I was trying to think how it would work and if, like the trial users, individuals could only complete it once/week.

Comment: Do you believe their consciousness really was uploaded? My reading of the episode was, when they die, they die, and the company was cynically exploiting how convincingly human-seeming its AI was to manipulate long term patients like Yorkie and Kelly to agree to spend more then euthanize themselves (freeing up space for new patients/customers) - everyone believing they'd live happy ever after, but actually the permanent residents are all just ['NPC's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-player_character), with behaviour based on observations of what they do when they 'visit'...

Comment: @Alarion Because your paid users a) already paid and b) are too dead to request refunds? This is Black Mirror after all...

Comment: @user568458 Given that the "uploaded" consciousness wouldn't be the original anyway, is there even a difference?